# Switch maven version - mvn command does not get bound

Tags: java, linux, shell, maven

I'm trying to switch maven from 2 to 3 (on Linux) using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set mvn /path/to/maven3/bin/mvn
```

Anyway `mvn -v` still gives version 2, so I always have to execute `/path/to/maven3/bin/mvn` to use maven. How can I rebind the mvn command to the appropriate maven path?

Comment: This a linux configuration question, not a programming question.  It would be better asked / answered on "superuser".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which mvn`

And then recreate symbolic link to point on new Maven version. And verify than environment variable `MAVEN_HOME` points to the right directory.

Comment: `which mvn: mvn/bin/maven2` - how do I recreate symbolic link?

Comment: there is likely a symlink named "maven" which points to "maven2". If you read the manual installation instructions [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/installation-sect-maven-install.html) it talks about creating the symlink (which is simply to ensure that you don't have to change too many things when you update to a new version.

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
```

Then choose which version you want use.

Also check than `which mvn` is symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/mvn`

Comment: I think this answer is more pointing into how to actually solve the problem. Although selected answer is helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Set system property M2_HOME to path to the maven home.